How to improve a model with little dataset?
I have a dataset that has 20 features and 65 samples. I did data scaling. I also did feature selection in different ways. But this is the result.
Test set evaluation:
_____________________________________
MAE: 2.3462910007887787
MSE: 8.68486045116839
RMSE: 2.947008729401457
R2 Square 0.11298965960629503
__________________________________
Train set evaluation:
_____________________________________
MAE: 1.9746175830150061
MSE: 6.369273380984405
RMSE: 2.5237419402514996
R2 Square 0.45535061890623796
__________________________________
adj r2 train 0.4008856807968617
adj r2 test -0.12354643116535957 

I worked on different models and the best results were on linear models like linear regression. Do you have a way to improve the models and results?

How are you calculating the test set adjusted r-squared?

If the linear models perform the best, and there are no serious mis-specifications present, then there is nothing to improve. Machine learning methods do not necessarily beat vanilla regressions, and often they don't. The real question is why the linear model is doing better. Perhaps it deals with the information more efficiently. Perhaps the regression line is fitting an association that doesn't actually exist. One needs to investigate the data before making any firm conclusions about which model works best, and metrics like $R^2$ and MSE don't alone tell the story.
More telling is that you have a large number of predictors and a small amount of data (I assume "65 samples" actually means 65 observations). Your model is probably dangerously overfitting the data, and this would be something else to consider.

+1. But any model that achieves a negative adjusted R-squared on its test set isn't actually fitting anything... .

I didn't even notice that til you pointed it out, and that is additional cause for concern.

If the model is not fitted at all, what could be the problem? @whuber

+1. Given the hugely overparameterized model, one should look into regularization. Take a look at the Lasso (Statistical Learning with Sparsity by Haste et al. is good), or the Elastic Net.
